# How can I set facebook meta tags dynamically?

Tags: php, jquery, facebook, opencart

I have an opencart site, and I'm trying to configure facebook share options of my products.

Since everything is loaded as a separate module, I can't set the facebook meta tags like this (`header.tpl`):

```
<meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo $description; ?>" />
```

Because the `$description` doesn't exist while the `header` module is loading.It is created in the controller of `product` module. So I tried to change the content value dynamically (`product.tpl`):

```
$("meta[property='og:description']").attr('content','<?php echo $description; ?>');
```

And it worked, I can see that the value is changed (in the page source), then I [debugged](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) my page but I couldn't get the value.. I think I know the reason, I have to set the value before the page load but I'm not sure how can I do that.. do you have any idea ?

Comment: Our crawler don't run Javascript. So you can't change them using Javascript

Comment: Unfortunately you would need to check in the header controller whether the page being displayed is a category, product, information page or manufacturer and in these cases load their respective details that will be then filled into the template. In template again listen for a variable representing such state to render the FB metatags accordingly. Little bit work has to be done unfortunately.

Comment: @shadyyx I thought the same thing but I was hoping there is another way.. it seems there is not.

Comment: Well right now I am inspecting the `controller::render()` method and I think you could succeed in passing the `$this->data` from `render()` into the `getChild()` call - this way with only little effort all the data from the main content could be shared among the *children* (header, footer, columns, ...). Then You should be able to simply use that variables from main content e.g. in your header to check if they are present and if yes then render the FB metatags... This should have less effort on programming but could cause unneeded and unwanted memory consumption increase (maybe only a little).

Comment: @shadyyx I end up with an easier solution, you might wanna have a look :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [Document](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/master/upload/system/library/document.php) class to add those facebook tags (as many as you want). Just add two extra methods `setFacebookDescription` and `getFacebookDescription`, so you have to add the followings:

```
<?php
class Document {
    private $facebook_description;

    public function getFacebookDescription() {
        return $this->facebook_description;
    }

    public function setFacebookDescription($facebook_description) {
        $this->facebook_description = $facebook_description;
    }
}
```

On each controller, you will find at the end of each method, a call which loads the header of Opencart, something like this `$data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');` ([example](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/master/upload/catalog/controller/product/product.php)). Note that it might differ from yours, it depends on Opencart version.

Now, in [header.php](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/master/upload/catalog/controller/common/header.php) controller you add:

```
<?php
class ControllerCommonHeader extends Controller {

    public function index() {
        $data['facebook_description'] = $this->document->getFacebookDescription();
    }
}
```

this will get the `facebook_description` variable and pass it to the view [header.tpl](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/master/upload/catalog/view/theme/default/template/common/header.tpl). Next, add the facebook tags between your `<head>` tags in `header.tpl` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <?php if ($facebook_description != '') { ?><meta property="og:description" content="<?php echo $facebook_description; ?>" /><?php } ?>
</head>
```

Finally, you can set facebook_description in each controller, by calling `$this->document->setFacebookDescription('my description');`.

Example: in [product.php controller](https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/master/upload/catalog/controller/product/product.php) you add

```
<?php
class ControllerProductProduct extends Controller {

    public function index() {

        // code...
        $this->document->setTitle($product_info['meta_title']);
        $this->document->setDescription($product_info['meta_description']);

        $this->document->setFacebookDescription($product_info['meta_description']);

        // the rest of the code...
    }
}
```

here you set the `$product_info['meta_description']` as facebook description tag, however you could also use `$product_info['name']` or other variable.

**Final note:** you can change all the Opencart system classes with the vqmod.

Comment: thanks for your time and the solution.this is a good idea, I will try this as soon as I can. it seems it would work, also it can be extended for other meta tags as you said...